# IIF can't divide given value if case is TRUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

`'ItemCount'` is equal to 2 but `CASE WHEN` or `IIF` function can't display `TRUE` results value.

QUERY:

```
SELECT
  c.Dscription,
  b.BaseRef AS 'DocNum',
  b.Ref2 AS 'NumatCard',
  CASE
    WHEN c.ItemCount = 2 THEN (b.BalDueDeb - b.BalDueCred) / 2
    ELSE (b.BalDueDeb - b.BalDueCred)
  END AS 'Balance'
FROM OJDT a
INNER JOIN JDT1 b
  ON a.TransID = b.Transid
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT
  t2.docnum,
  t3.Dscription,
  t2.TransId,
  (COUNT(t3.ItemCode) AS 'ItemCount'
FROM OINV T2
INNER JOIN INV1 T3
  ON T2.DocEntry = T3.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN ORIN v
  ON LEFT(v.NumAtCard, 6) = LEFT(t2.NumAtCard, 6)
LEFT JOIN RCT2 s
  ON s.baseAbs = t2.DocEntry
WHERE t3.Quantity > 0
AND t2.CANCELED = 'N'
GROUP BY t2.docnum,
         T2.TransId,
         t3.Dscription,
         t3.ItemCode
HAVING COUNT(t2.DocNum) = 1) c
  ON a.TransId = c.TransId
INNER JOIN OACT T5
  ON T5.AcctCode = b.Account
INNER JOIN OCRD T1
  ON b.ShortName = T1.CardCode
  AND T1.CardType = 'C'
WHERE T5.FORMATCODE = 11020103
AND (b.balduecred <> 0
OR b.balduedeb != 0)
AND b.BaseRef = 100078166
GROUP BY c.Dscription,
         b.BaseRef,
         b.Ref2,
         b.BalDueDeb,
         b.BalDueCred,
         c.ItemCount
```

RESULT:

```
Dscription      DocNum      NumatCard   Balance
CAREER GUIDE    100078166   88920-42    10560
CLASSIFINDER    100078166   88920-42    10560
```

SHOULD BE:

```
Dscription      DocNum      NumatCard   Balance
CAREER GUIDE    100078166   88920-42    5280
CLASSIFINDER    100078166   88920-42    5280
```

DATA:

```
Dscription      DocNum      NumatCard   Balance   ItemCount   Quantity
CAREER GUIDE    100078166   88920-42    5280      2           24
CLASSIFINDER    100078166   88920-42    5280      2           24
DISPLAY         100048374   551493      9623      1           15
DISPLAY         100048586   551894      10483     2           17
CAREER GUIDE    100048586   551894      10483     2           17
```

Comment: Sorry, still new to stackoverflow and don't know how to post it as a table.
Not an IT too but i'm learning codes from someone and I really can't get above error :). Thanks for understanding.

Comment: 1. MySQL does not have iif() function. MS Access and MS SQL Server do. MySQL has if(). Are you sure that you use MySQL? 2. It is pretty difficult to tell what may have gone wrong without any sample data. My guess is that the itemcount is not 2, but sg different because trust me, case and if() both can handle simple equality tests.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008. ItemCount is equal to the count of Dscription thou.

Comment: Include `ItemCount` in your output to *verify* that it matches your assumptions.

Comment: I added c.ItemCount on the query.

**NEW RESULT:**

Dscription         DocNum         NumatCard Balance ItemCount
CAREER GUIDE 100078166 88920-42         10560 2
CLASSIFINDER 100078166 88920-42         10560 2

Comment: The code is appallingly messy - can't you use a `WITH` clause to move some of the logic out of the main query? Also, have you verified what (BalDueDeb - BalDueCred) actually is, to close that side of the problem off? I'm assuimg maybe somewhere in there what is happening is that two rows for each item are being `GROUP BY`ed, countering the division you're doing in the `SELECT`, but I can't quite tell.

Comment: We really need some sample data here. Without knowing the data behind the query, we can't hope to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I realise this isn't an answer to the question, but we have no sample data to base it on. What I had to do was fix the SQL a little; perhaps it'll help others answer the question instead.

A few points, which I do put in the comments. There is no need for the use of `DISTINCT` in the `SELECT` statement that has a `GROUP BY`. This would just be added overhead for the server, but would provide no additional benefit.

Also, aliases. When you aliases an object, use something that is representative of the object. Calling things `a`, `b`, `t1`, `t2` in every query isn't helpful, as someone else reading your code will have to go through the `FROM` clauses every time they're looking at an alias (especially as in your original query, they were all over the place). The tables in your query have very short names anyway, so really no need to alias. If, however, you had larger names, then use helpful aliases. For example maybe `C` for `Customer`, `CO` for `CustomerOrder`, `BAD` for `BusinessAddressData` (you get the idea).

As I hope you can appreciate, it would be very confusing for someone if in one query the table `Customer` is aliased `T1` and `CustomerOrder` is `T2`, but in another `Customer` is `T3`, `BusinessAddressData` is T1 and `CustomerOrder` is `a`.

Anyway, here's a (I feel) more readable version of the same query:

```
WITH Docs AS ( --Put your LEFT JOIN on a SELECT Statement into a CTE 
    SELECT OINV.docnum, --There was no need for a DISTINCT here, you are using GROUP BY
           INV1.Dscription,
           O.TransId,
           COUNT(INV1.ItemCode) AS ItemCount --Why cast a COUNT  to an INT? COUNT returns an INT. The CAST would just create extra overhead.
    FROM OINV --Use helpful Aliases. These object only have 4 character names, so really no need to use an Alias
         INNER JOIN INV1 ON OINV.DocEntry = INV1.DocEntry
         LEFT JOIN ORIN ON LEFT(ORIN.NumAtCard, 6) = LEFT(OINV.NumAtCard, 6) 
         LEFT JOIN RCT2 ON RCT2.baseAbs = OINV.DocEntry
    WHERE INV1.Quantity > 0
      AND OINV.CANCELED = 'N'
    GROUP BY OINV.docnum,
             OINV.TransId,
             INV1.Dscription,
             INV1.ItemCode
    HAVING COUNT(OINV.DocNum) = 1)

SELECT Docs.Dscription,
       JDT1.BaseRef AS DocNum,
       JDT1.Ref2 AS NumatCard,
       CASE WHEN Docs.ItemCount = 2 THEN (JDT1.BalDueDeb - JDT1.BalDueCred) / 2
                                 ELSE (JDT1.BalDueDeb - JDT1.BalDueCred)
       END AS Balance
FROM OJDT --Again, no need for Aliases such as a, b, c. They aren't helpful. When looking at code, an Alias should be representative of the object's name
     INNER JOIN JDT1 ON OJDT.TransID = JDT1.Transid
     LEFT JOIN Docs ON OJDT.TransId = Docs.TransId
     INNER JOIN OACT ON JDT1.Account = OACT.AcctCode
     INNER JOIN OCRD ON JDT1.CardCode = OCRD.ShortName
WHERE OCRD.CardType = 'C';
```